# Scala: val with volatile type overriding def with non-volatile type

Tags: scala

I'm stuck trying to understand Scala doesn't allow the following:

```
trait WhatsWrong {
  type Foo

  trait HasFoo {
    def foo: Foo
  }

  type Foo2 = Foo with HasFoo2

  trait HasFoo2 extends HasFoo {
    override val foo: Foo2 // <-- error here
 // override def foo: Foo2 // <-- this works though
  }
}
```

> Error: overriding method foo in trait HasFoo of type => WhatsWrong.this.Foo;
>    value foo has a volatile type; cannot override a member with non-volatile type
>   `override val foo: WhatsWrong.this.Foo2`

Why `Foo2` is a volatile type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo2` is volatile according to http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#volatile-types: the second case holds: `Foo2 = T1 with T2` with T1 being abstract and T2 contributing an abstract type member.

This error message always comes when you override a non-volatile type with a volatile type: `Foo` is non-volatile (because none of 1.-3. apply). So, to make the error go away, there are a few possible ways:

- make `HasFoo.foo`s return type volatile. This can be done by using `Foo with Foo` instead of just `Foo` (according to 3.6.1). I think, other than that, there's no difference between `Foo with Foo` and just `Foo`. So the following code compiles:

  ```
  trait WhatsWrong {
    type Foo

    trait HasFoo {
      def foo: Foo with Foo
    }

    type Foo2 = Foo with HasFoo2

    trait HasFoo2 extends HasFoo {
      override val foo: Foo2 // <-- hey, now this works :)
      // override def foo: Foo2 // <-- this works, too
    }
  }
  ```
- hm, I thought there would be something possible with @uncheckedStable (see http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html#scala-compiler-annotations), but this doesn't seem to be the case: Annotating the volatile value with @annotations.unchecked.uncheckedStable doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I think you have a typo: "Foo~~2~~ is non-volatile (because none of 1.-3. apply)". Looks correct otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before, it's related to the dynamic nature of abstract (not yet defined) accessors like val and def. In this case, just use def instead of val and it will compile.

```
trait HasFoo2 extends HasFoo {
    override def foo: Foo2 // <-- error here
    // override def foo: Foo2 // <-- this works though
  }
```